# Is MSO Rep worth trying to gain?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

Is it worth answering here because of rep, or should you take it as a charity work?

For example, do you put your MSO Flair on your blog?

Comment: How do I close this as "belongs on meta-meta.stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: Just select any other option and pretend

Comment: Because it's fun.

Comment: Oh boy, pretend!  That's where I'm a viking!

Comment: You can't afford *not to* -- MSO rep is currently trading at `FILE_NOT_FOUND` points to the dollar!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Arguably, SO rep isn't even worth it. That doesn't mean I'll quit answering questions.

Comment: mmyers, wherever you are at the moment, I hope you can hear me applauding.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Rep on SO borders on meaningless, but it does allow you to do nice things like edit and close OT posts. Also, it's a fun game to play with your peers.

Rep on MSO just indicates that you have too much time on your hands. You should not only *avoid* posting flair, you should hide it like the shameful secret that it is...

Comment: Which explains why you CW'd this post.

Comment: and to think I just wasted all that printer ink printing copies of my flair to plaster all over my walls and to create "StackExchange Consulting" business cards.

Comment: StackExchange consulting?  Now there's a business idea ( _if_ a lot of people actually start using the service).

Comment: @mmyers: i crave the sting of the coming down-votes. It will be like a fresh, cold can of Mountain Dew to my ego, if MD actually did what the commercials imply.

Comment: (but yes, my assertions would be a whole lot more punchy if my MSO rep wasn't displayed, in bold, *right next to them* )

Comment: You'd probably get more down-votes if you left it at "No."

Comment: Putting SO flair on your blog is akin to placing all your used heroin needles in a trophy case at your front door.

Comment: Shog9: I'm failing to see why your post is specific to MSO and not general to all the SO sites :)

Answer (score 4):

I will give the obligatory "Yes" answer, because if I say no, I will feel really sad about the time I have spent trying to get it here :)

Comment: Of course the answer is yes.  If we didn't have all this rep, we couldn't have fixed this question.  And then everyone suffers.

Comment: If a question has bad grammar in a forest, and no one is there to read it, does anyone suffer?

Comment: The world suffers.

Comment: @mmyers: Shoot, I was always bad at riddles.  I'm still trying to figure out what color the bear is if I edit a question in a cabin where all four walls face south.

Comment: You're bad at shooting riddles? That's probably why the bear is still alive.

Comment: Does the Pope defecate in the woods?

Comment: @belgarion: That is truly one of the most wtf comments I've ever seen. Bravo.

Comment: Apricots        .

Comment: @belgariontheking: If he does, I hope he'd edit the question with bad grammar while he's there.

Comment: @TheTXI: Are you claiming that the Pope does not digest apricots and defecates them in a form that can be readily identified as such?

Comment: @belgariontheking: No, I am trying to assert that the crux of this debate is analagous to the pit of an apricot that was crushed underneath the foot of the bear that was defecating on the four south-facing walls.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if a bear is defecating on the walls of my cabin, then we have the answer to mmyers's question about who suffers: the Pope.

Comment: @TheTXI: That makes total sense, as the four south-facing walls are the walls of a mushroom.  It's easy to defecate on mushrooms.  Not so easy: editing questions while you're covered in bear apricots, crushed or not.

Comment: @belgariontheking: Now I think you're just being pretentious.

Comment: @TheTXI: Don't be jealous because you're not Catholic when you're in the forest.

Comment: @belgariontheking: I would expect a Calvinist to say something to that extent. Your grasp of the bear mauling the defecating pope is flimsy and the fact that you believe that my belief in the pope's apriocot scent only shows that your grasp of the south-facing mushroom is inconsequential at best.

Comment: @TheTXI: Technically, the Pope smells of apricots *and nuts*.  The point is moot, though, because what is a question with bad grammar going to do with some nuts?

Comment: @Pesto: Parcheesi.

Comment: FECAL DAMN IT!  How many times do we have to tell you that the pope does not smell like cheese!  In other news, 6 year old boys smell like cheese.

Comment: @Pesto: The nuts will edit the question and then have an inane discussion in the comments, of course.

Comment: @TheTXI: According to the Calvinists, if the Pope plays Parcheesi with a defecating bear in a cabin in the woods, it is because God has ordained that it will happen.

Comment: @Pesto: But can God navigate Himself out of the room with all four walls facing south while the defecating bear is busy playing parcheesi with the apricot-smelling pope? Or will he have to partake in a magic mushroom to achieve proper MP?

Comment: @Pesto: The Pope in fact /did/ defecate on a bear who was playing Parcheesi, but it's not because God ordained it to be.  No, we can put that responsibility square on the shoulders of Michael Jackson.

Comment: @belgariontheking: BLASPHEMER!

Comment: @TheTXI: I think the incantation for *Escape Cabin via South-facing Wall* requires spell components.  So, proper MP or not, unless He has an eye of newt and an apricot pit, He is stuck until he rolls doubles.

Comment: @Pesto: will the spell still work if the apricot pit was obtained from the droppings of the defecating bear?

Comment: It also has vocal requirements, so bears cannot cast it. It also has somatic requirements so the Pope can only cast it if he's done his stretches for the day and is not currently covered in feces. Come to think of it, the feces would hinder the Pope's movements too, but only until he figures out how to get the bear to hold his nose while he dances around like Michael Jackson

Comment: I think this has become the most fecal and intertwined thread in all of SO!

Comment: @voyager: You'd think so, but God has ordained that it can get *much* more fecal, but only if it's in a forest and there's no one around to read it.

Comment: @Pesto: Do you remember what God said about the bisexual monkeys?  Do we need to bring them into the thread or keep them out?

Comment: @belgariontheking: You just enacted the Godwin's Law of nonsense: whoever first mentions monkeys is the loser.

Comment: @Pesto: But God mentioned them first!

Answer (score 2):

It's worth it earning up to 10K so you have full voting, editing, and viewing privileges.  Beyond that, less so.

Note that earning rep is different from participating in the site.  If you use StackOverflow, ServerFault, or SuperUser, it's worth your while to keep an eye on meta now and then.

Comment: Or else just become a moderator.

Comment: @mmyers: Or steal a moderator's login information.

Comment: @mmyers: That takes a whole new spin with your new diamond.  Incidentally, you got 10k on Meta about a week before that, so apparently 10k is still the quicker path!

Comment: @Gnome: It was more like a month, I think. But yeah.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put my MSO flair on any external site mainly because it's meaningless outside the SO sites.

Having said that I wouldn't put my SO flair on other sites either. I experimented with it on my Facebook profile and my blog (for different reasons), but I've removed it from both.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If I were you I wouldn't care past 100:

```
1        Leave comments
15       Vote up
15       Flag offensive
100      Vote down (costs 1 rep), create new tags, edit community wiki posts
250      Vote to close or reopen your questions, create new tags
500      Retag questions
2000     Edit other people's posts
3000     Vote to close or reopen any questions
10000    Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
```

That said, I hope a bunch of people get to 10K.

Comment: I like      you.

Comment: I know you have the cheat codes, Tom. I tried up up down down left right left right a b a b select start to no avail. Does Game Genie work on this thing?

Comment: If I had 2000 rep, I'd edit out the extra "were". Come on people, give me 196 upvotes! Not that I care, of course.

Comment: @mmyers: No upvotes for you, but I edited the question.  So it's a wash, really.

Comment: The Contra code does work, it's how I got the ♦, but you need a real peripheral. http://www.blogiversity.org/blogs/frankthetank/ba5a_retro_nes_usb_controller-1.jpg